# What's the best way to use distributed multi-GPU inferencing in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, distributed-computing, tensorflow-datasets

I am new to Tensorflow and I am working on distributing testing images to multiple GPUs. I have read a lot of Stack overflow answers and Github examples, and I think there might be two ways to do that.

1) using tf.FIFOQueue() to feed each GPU images, however the queue is not recommended in a lot of answers (due to the new tf.data API). And it has some issues (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8061)

2) using tf.data API. I am not sure if this API support GPU or not. In this issue (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13610), it seems that input pipeline with tf.data API can not support GPU feeding yet.

Distributed Tensorflow is not within my consideration (since our model and scale of server is not that large)

I will appreciate it very much if some one can give me any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tf.data`. The `tf.data` API is meant to replace almost every functionality of queues and makes everything easier and more performant.

It can also feed data to the GPU. The second issue you link to just says that the preprocessing will not happen on the GPU, but data will be processed on CPU and then sent to your multiple GPUs.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I recently have started to use data set API and I was recommended using 'dataset.shard' function for distributed GPUs. But in the official documents there's not much information about how to use it. Do you have experience working with it before?